# Telegram Bot Check If Member In Group Is Deleted

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to code a telegram bot to remove any deleted accounts in the group chat but with telegram removing get_chat_members in later versions I'm at a lost, here's my current code how can I get all the members or loop through all members to check rather the account is deleted or not?

```
from telegram import *
from telegram.ext import * 
from requests import *
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
from telegram.ext import CallbackQueryHandler, CallbackContext
from telegram.ext.dispatcher import run_async
from telegram.ext.jobqueue import Days

# Create a new Telegram bot & # Start the bot and connect to the Telegram API
updater = Updater(token="bot_token", use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

# Define a command handler for the /start command, which prints a greeting
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Hello! I am RDA_bot, a bot that removes deleted accounts from a Telegram group.")
    
    # Define a command handler for the /remove command, which removes deleted accounts from the group
def remove(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    # Get a list of all members of the group
    members = #NEED HELP HERE

  # Count how many members have deleted their account
    deleted_accounts = 0
    for member in members:
     if member.user.is_deleted:
      deleted_accounts += 1

  # Send a message to the user with the number of deleted accounts
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=f"Removed {deleted_accounts} deleted accounts from the group.")

# Define a command handler for the /remove command, which removes deleted accounts from the group
def remove(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
  # Get a list of all members of the group
  members = #NEED HELP HERE

  # Loop through each member of the group
  for member in members:
    # If the member's account has been deleted, kick them from the group
    if member.user.is_deleted: #NEED TO CHECK IF THE USER IS DELETED
      context.bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, user_id=member.user.id, until_date=0)

# Create a job that runs every 24 hours to remove deleted accounts from the group
job_queue = updater.job_queue
job = job_queue.run_repeating(remove, interval=Days(1), first=0)

# Add the command handlers to the dispatcher
start_handler = CommandHandler("start", start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
remove_handler = CommandHandler("remove", remove)
dispatcher.add_handler(remove_handler)

# Start the bot
updater.start_polling()
```

tried get_chat_members(chat_id) but that's no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) does not contain functionality to retrieve the full member list of a chat. I'm also not aware of any reliable way of checking if an account has been deleted. Maybe [`getChat`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchat) returns a helpful error message in that case, but I haven't tried that so far.